# Redirect a custom form to django admin form

Tags: django, django-admin

I created a custom admin form for a particular model. All functionalities working. Now I want to call this form from the click of a button on another page that I have created. I was able to do that by creating an object of the form class, but it doesn't render the form as the admin site does (I had some fieldsets etc defined). Can I straight away redirect to the admin site's form? That would avoid duplicating the code for how I handle the form data. Any other leads would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to call this form from the click of a button on another page that I have created.

Is this also within the admin interface? If so, don't use the admin view for all your users. As that will require nasty stuff with groups, permissions, etc.

> I was able to do that by creating an object of the form class, but it doesn't render the form as the admin site does (I had some fieldsets etc defined).

Isn't this as expected, as the admin site comes with its own css and javascript? So you need to write it yourself

> Can I straight away redirect to the admin site's form? That would avoid
>   duplicating the code for how I handle the form data. Any other leads
>   would also be appreciated.

True, but I believe the admin views have special authorisation checks on them. So you come back to the things with groups and permissions.

What I would do is move your form handling to an method in like `utils.py` and call this method from the normal and admin view.

Comment: I do not have issues with the permissions, everything I've stated here is within the admin interface itself, and I wouldn't want to write my own CSS/JS for this form, seems like an overkill.
(I was able to get around by hardcoding the url in my form though!)